# Ioctl succeeds in changing MAC address but returns error

Tags: c, linux, sockets, mac-address, ioctl

I'm trying to write a c program to change the MAC address of the wireless interface ('`wlp2s0`' on my system). The call to `ioctl` successfully changes the MAC address (which I verified using `ifconfig`) but returns an error (Too many open files). The following is my program

```
int main(void)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sockfd;

    bzero(ifr.ifr_name, IFNAMSIZ);
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "wlp2s0");

    printf("Type in new MAC address here: ");
    scanf("%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx",
           &ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[0],
           &ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1],
           &ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2],
           &ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3],
           &ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4],
           &ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[5]
    );

    ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_family = ARPHRD_ETHER;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
           perror("socket: Failed to open socket");
           exit(1);
    }

    if(ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFHWADDR, &ifr) < 0)
    {
           perror("ioctl: Failed to change MAC address");
           exit(2);
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this program, I get the following error:

```
ioctl: Failed to change MAC address: Too many open files in system
```

But `ifconfig` shows that the MAC address has successfully been changed. Why then, am I getting this error?

Comment: what kernel version ?

Comment: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-907162-start-0.html may help

Comment: take the interface down before changing the MAC address and back up after

Comment: @tofro according to the link I posted above that's probably correct, but it's odd (i.e. probably a driver bug) that the change apparently succeeds and yet still returns `-ENFILE`

Comment: As a sanity check, do you get the same behavior if you put `errno = 0;` immediately before the `if(ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFHWADDR, &ifr) < 0)` line?

Comment: @zwol I tried `errno = 0;` before the `ioctl` but the problem persists.

Comment: Then this is definitely a bug in the kernel.  System calls aren't supposed to succeed and yet return an error code.